# Is it possible to import burst stacks to the simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I need to have burst stacks in the bursts smart album in the simulator for testing. Is it possible to import burst photos to the simulator? And if so, how?

Comment: I never did find a way, but leaving this question open in case someone eventually figures it out.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: At least at the time it was not possible (confirmed with Photos team engineers). I haven't checked in a while, but I assume it's still not possible.